# How do I change the keyboard map for Backspace?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My keyboard doesn't have a delete key. I want to be able to use "delete" when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

How would I go about doing this?

And then how would I then use this edited layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do that:

1. Install `xbindkeys` and `xautomation`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
   ```
2. Find the binding of your <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut. Run:

   ```
   xbindkeys -mk
   ```

   A blank window will open, press your <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut. That will output in the terminal something like this :

   ```
   m:0x11 + c:22        
   Shift+Mod2 + BackSpace
   ```
3. Create your configuration file :

   ```
   xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
4. Open this file with a text editor (`gedit .xbindkeysrc`) and add at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   "xte 'key Delete'"
   m:0x11 + c:22        
   Shift+Mod2 + BackSpace
   ```

   And save.

Log out and re-login and your <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut should now work properly.

---

Refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts) for more information on `xautomation`.

Comment: I followed your instructions and the key isn't working.
I also tried to follow the information on xautomation.
I installed the GUI and saw that your instructions made the proper keybind, but whenever I try to use Shift + Backspace, nothing happens.
I have restarted the computer too.
Note: I'm using crouton on a chromebook, so I'm not sure if that effects anything. Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup user hot-keys and shortcuts, This is some helpful documents that may help best luck! Grab a plug and play keyboard when you can! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts